# How can I make the decimal places of AVG function in sql limit to 2 only?

Tags: mysql

I want to limit the decimal of the average to 2..

```
SELECT grade.GStudNo, AVG(grade.Grade) AS Average, students.LName, students.FName, students.MName, students.Course
FROM students INNER JOIN grade ON students.StudNo = grade.GStudNo
WHERE GSem = '$sem' AND GYear = '$year'
GROUP BY grade.GStudNo
ORDER BY Average ASC LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 55):

```
SELECT grade.GStudNo, ROUND( AVG(grade.Grade),2 ) AS Average, students.LName, students.FName, students.MName, students.Course
FROM students INNER JOIN grade ON students.StudNo = grade.GStudNo
WHERE GSem = '$sem' AND GYear = '$year'
GROUP BY grade.GStudNo
ORDER BY Average ASC LIMIT 3
```

Would round it to two places.

Answer (score 15):

use the `ROUND` function to wrap the AVG calculation...

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you are looking for this :

```
SELECT grade.GStudNo, CAST(AVG(grade.Grade) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Average, students.LName, students.FName, students.MName, students.Course
FROM students INNER JOIN grade ON students.StudNo = grade.GStudNo
WHERE GSem = '$sem' AND GYear = '$year'
GROUP BY grade.GStudNo
ORDER BY Average ASC LIMIT 3
```

this get only 2 decimals

```
CAST(AVG(grade.Grade) AS DECIMAL(10,2))
```