# How to round off the value in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`brambang`@`%` PROCEDURE `TNP_PRODUK_FrekuensiPembelianUlang`(IN paramdatefrom CHAR(19), paramdateto CHAR(19))
BEGIN
SELECT MAX(count) AS max,
       MIN(count) AS min,
       AVG(count) AS average,
       AVG(CASE WHEN rn IN (FLOOR((@tr+1)/2), FLOOR((@tr+2)/2)) THEN count END) AS median
FROM (
  SELECT count, 
         @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn,
         @tr := @rn AS tr
  FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM order_match om1
    where om1.createdAt between paramdatefrom and paramdateto
    and om1.order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
    and EXISTS(SELECT 1 from order_match om2
    where om1.createdby = om2.createdby
    and om2.createdAt < paramdatefrom
    and om2.order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8))
    GROUP BY createdby
    ORDER BY count
  ) o
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) init
) c;

END
```

and this is the result if i insert the parameter

```
+-----+-----+---------+---------+
| max | min | average | median  |
+-----+-----+---------+---------+
|  24 |   1 |  1.6382 | 1.00000 |
+-----+-----+---------+---------+
```

What should I add to my stored procedure so that the value can be rounded off to be like this

```
    +-----+-----+---------+---------+
    | max | min | average | median  |
    +-----+-----+---------+---------+
    |  24 |   1 |  1.64   |     1.0 |
    +-----+-----+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make the decimal places of AVG function in sql limit to 2 only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316121/how-can-i-make-the-decimal-places-of-avg-function-in-sql-limit-to-2-only)

Comment: Do you really need to do it in the database? If it is only for display then rather do it in the display layer

Comment: yes sir, because i need it for display on my internal company website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ROUND()`. If you want two decimals maximum, then:

```
SELECT ROUND(MAX(count), 2) AS max,
       ROUND(MIN(count), 2) AS min,
       ROUND(AVG(count), 2) AS average,
       ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN rn IN (FLOOR((@tr+1)/2), FLOOR((@tr+2)/2)) THEN count END), 2) AS median
FROM ...
```