# Is there way to output no decimal using mysql AVG() function

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT AVG(
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, 
                          customer_service_ticket_raise_time, 
                          CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
            )
        ) AS avg_waiting_time 
FROM customer_service_ticket;
```

I am writing this SQL query to display the average waiting time customers have been waiting but it outputs as  a decimal value e.g. 29.8333. Is there any way I want get rid of the decimals and display the minutes as a whole value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316121/how-can-i-make-the-decimal-places-of-avg-function-in-sql-limit-to-2-only

Answer (score -1):

you can wrap your value with the CEILING function

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_ceiling.asp